# Objective-C Bloggers

Tags: objective-c, blogs

I've been primarily developing in c# for the last few years and have found that staying up-to-date with some of the best c# blogs (Ayende, Jeremy Miller, Greg Young, Phil Haack, et al) has been invaluable. So, I'm just getting into objective-c and iPhone development and am wondering who are the top bloggers I should be keeping up with are.

Answer (score 3):

I enjoy these:

- [cocoa is my girlfriend](http://www.cimgf.com/feed/)
- [cocoa with love](http://cocoawithlove.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=rss)
- [icode blog](http://icodeblog.com/feed/)
- [iphone dev tricks](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/feed)
- [iphone dev](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=rss)

Answer (score 2):

You can check answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232567/best-cocoa-mac-os-x-programming-blogs).

Answer (score 2):

There are a ton of Objective-C / Cocoa / iPhone coders on Twitter...so I would look into setting up a Twitter account if you haven't already.

Answer (score 0):

[CocoaCast](http://cocoacast.com/?q=blog/1) is a great resource. You will also find a list of Cocoa blogs [here](http://cocoablogs.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Another good one that is sadly not updated as often as it should be is [Call Me Fishmeal](http://www.wilshipley.com/blog/).  It's a mix of personal stuff along with a section called "Pimp My Code", where he goes into great detail on how to write excellent Objective C code.

Answer (score 0):

I second the twitter recommendation, but Planet Cocoa (planetcocoa.org) is a must, it collates a wide range of Macintosh/iPhone developer blogs

Answer (score 0):

I've got a pretty good list of Cocoa related blogs and podcasts on [this blog post](http://www.shauber.net/2008/07/podcasts-blogs/).